# variable is assigned a null value in jmeter beanshell sampler

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Hi I am trying to assign value extracted from one sampler to another variable in a beanshell script.
I have the below beanshell script.

```
  vars.put("linkArr",vars.get("${PlanLinksArray_1}"));
```

the text request in jmeter is showing the below for beanshell sampler

```
vars.put("linkArr",vars.get("9PacMiSVl6GIQAtco747NQ"));
```

but the linkArr variable is showing a null value in the debug sampler.

why is that i am getting a null value when I am expecting 9PacMiSVl6GIQAtco747NQ value to be assigned to the linkArr variable. please suggest

[image: beanshell request shown below]

[image: debug sampler result for linkArr shown below]

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 2):

You try to get the value of a variable named `9PacMiSVl6GIQAtco747NQ`.
As such variable doesn't exist, your `vars.get` returns null.

This is because

1. The variable `${}` gets resolved and becomes a string value.
2. The beanshell function is executed and tries to get a variable with the in 1st resolved variable-name.

In general: Within beanshell `${}` is almost never needed (except for very specific purposes).

Try this instead:

```
vars.put("linkArr",vars.get("PlanLinksArray_1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

> vars.put("linkArr",vars.get("PlanLinksArray_1"));